# Get unordered data from a tbl in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with some records, ex:

```
tblONE(numop, ordop, numsav, dateop)
```

some records where loaded sequencially, but someothers don't, i wish to get those data report

`select * from talONE where numop or ordop or numsav or date` is no ordered?

there is a way to get it?

EDIT:

example tblONE

```
numop ordop  numsav    dateop
3       1      5    1/1/22 00:00:01
3       2      6    1/1/22 00:00:02
3       3      7    1/1/22 00:00:04
12      5      3    5/1/22 00:00:15
12      2      9    5/1/22 00:00:17
12      18     1    5/1/22 00:00:23
12      9      15   5/1/22 00:00:32
12      1      6    5/1/22 00:00:05
23      5      13   10/1/22 00:00:02
23      6      26   10/1/22 00:00:03
23      9      34   10/1/22 00:00:04
23      17     41   10/1/22 00:00:05
435     45     9    13/1/22 00:00:21
435     12     3    13/1/22 00:00:22
435     62     62   13/1/22 00:00:25
```

numop 3 and 23 are ordered, i don't wanna see them, I want to see just the others (12, 435)

Comment: if you do not have an ORDER BY clause, then there is no order in the table.  Your question is unclear. show sample data and expected output as tables

Comment: if i don't have an order by, I'll see the unordered and ordered data, I don't want to see the ordered data

Comment: `DATE` is a reserved word and is not a valid (unquoted) column identifier. Also, `where numop or ordop or numsav or date` is not valid.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you want all the rows for a `numop` if any of them have either `ordop` or `numsav` (not sure if it matters which based on the sample data?) in a different order to the `dateop` - so to you they are 'ordered' if the `ordop` increases when the `dateop` does? It would help if you edit the question to clearly explain the logic you are applying, not least to avoid confusion with the concept of ordering a result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply an analytic ranking function to both the `ordop` and `dateop` columns:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by numop order by ordop)
dense_rank() over (partition by numop order by dateop)
```

and compare the results to look for a discrepancy; you can't use those in a `where` clause but you could use a subquery:

```
select numop, ordop, numsav, dateop
from tableone
where numop in (
  select numop
  from (
    select numop,
      dense_rank() over (partition by numop order by ordop) as ord_rnk,
      dense_rank() over (partition by numop order by dateop) as date_rnk
    from tableone
  )
  where ord_rnk != date_rnk
)
```

or CTEs:

```
with cte1 (numop, ordop, numsav, dateop, match) as (
  select numop, ordop, numsav, dateop,
  case
    when dense_rank() over (partition by numop order by ordop)
        = dense_rank() over (partition by numop order by dateop)
    then 'Match' else 'Mismatch'
  end
  from tableone
),
cte2 (numop, ordop, numsav, dateop, max_match) as (
  select numop, ordop, numsav, dateop, max(match) over (partition by numop)
  from cte1
)
select numop, ordop, numsav, dateop
from cte2
where max_match = 'Mismatch'
```

which both return:

| NUMOP | ORDOP | NUMSAV | DATEOP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 5 | 3 | 2022-01-05 00:00:15 |
| 12 | 2 | 9 | 2022-01-05 00:00:17 |
| 12 | 18 | 1 | 2022-01-05 00:00:23 |
| 12 | 9 | 15 | 2022-01-05 00:00:32 |
| 12 | 1 | 6 | 2022-01-05 00:00:05 |
| 435 | 45 | 9 | 2022-01-13 00:00:21 |
| 435 | 12 | 3 | 2022-01-13 00:00:22 |
| 435 | 62 | 62 | 2022-01-13 00:00:25 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7af631b085cb65da91b98462730543ec)

---

> it really worked till I realize some date are repeated

If you have duplicate dates you can break the tie consistently by including another column in the ranking for that; to stop false positives maybe:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by numop order by dateop, ordop)
```

Comment: it really worked till I realize some date are repeated

Comment: @egoigos - breaking the tie might be enough; see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have an `ORDER BY` clause then none of the rows are ordered (if they appear to be ordered then it is only coincidence).

From the [`SELECT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6):

> #### `order_by_clause`
>
> Use the `ORDER BY` clause to order rows returned by the statement. Without an `order_by_clause`, no guarantee exists that the same query executed more than once will retrieve rows in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Alex Poole and @MT0 for your replies,
I've just found the answer I was looking for, and it is:

```
SELECT NUMOP FROM (
            SELECT NUMOP,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY NUMOP ORDER BY DATEOP, ORDOP) AS DATE_RNK
            FROM TBLONE
    )
group by NUMOP;
```

thank you all, I hope this tip helps in a future to someone